# adding dynamic url to jenkins email body

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured a jenkins job to send email with the generated pdf files an attachment. Editable email notification plugin is used for this. However, I want to add the URL of the file in the email body, since this url is dynamic and changes as per the generated report, I haven't been able to achieve this. Is there any way to accomplish this task?